# Подключение виртуальной машины к Интернет

Tags: virtualbox

Есть рабочая машина с Windows-10 с доступом в Интернет через прокси.
На ней установлен virtual box, на котором развернута Slackware 14-2.
Можно ли как-то настроить для Slackware доступ к Интернет?

Comment: Можно, конечно. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_nat

Comment: Просто настроить в нём точно такой же прокси?

Comment: @andreymal, Пробовал, не помогло. Допускаю, что что-то делал неправильно, а найти описание всей процедуры пока не смог.

Comment: Как вариант по настройке прокси попробуйте создать переменные среды `http_proxy="http://user:password@ip:port"`, `ftp_proxy=ftp://...` и так далее.